# Connect to multiple PHP code through one Java async task

Tags: php, android, database

I am developing an app in which I need to update 2 PHP databases at the same time. From the first PHP DB I get the data which needs to be shown on the main screen, so it is handled in the onPostExecute. But for the second PHP DB I need to check and update the records I have in it, I cant figure out how to carry out multiple PHP requests in one Java program. The code is below:

Java code

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String json_url;
    Context context;

    public BackgroundTask (Context c) { context = c;}

    public BackgroundTask() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "... my link ..."; // to get data of the user
        if (type.equals("login")) {
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];

                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String results = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((STRING_JSON = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    results += line;
                    stringBuilder.append(STRING_JSON + "\n");

                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                //connectionStatus = true;
                Log.i("doInBackgroundTry->try", "stringbuilder in the end is " + stringBuilder.toString());
                master_string = stringBuilder.toString().trim();
                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "malformed exception error is " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        json_url = " ... my link ...";
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {

    // random updation of the UI

    }
}
```

All the second PHP DB has is an ID that will be checked if it was already in the table or not, if it is then nothing would happen but if it wasn't then it would be added into the DB.

Comment: you can try changing your type variable. Like when you are calling execute you must be telling it the type of method you use the php code, you can change your if ( type.equals("login") ) by adding another else if like this : else if ( type.equals ("second_query") ) ...

Comment: can you be more elaborate?

Comment: I will post an answer, I am pretty sure that my approach is correct ... wait for some time ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when calling the execute you must be passing the type via some function. You can do this again but with a different type to handle your second query. For example:

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String json_url;
    Context context;

    public BackgroundTask (Context c) { context = c;}

    public BackgroundTask() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "... my link ..."; // to get data of the user
        if (type.equals("login")) {

        return null;
    }

    else if (type.equals("second_query_type")
    {
        // bla bla bla 
        // random code bla bla bla

        // if you are not going to update your UI, then just return null here
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        json_url = " ... my link ...";
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {

    // random updation of the UI

    }
}
```

Now, you can execute the second query using three methods.

**Method 1: execute the execute via a function**

```
public void second_query_type(String type)
{
 new BackgroundTask(type);
}
```

**Method 2: create an object of background task and call the execute function**

```
BackgroundTask bt = new BackgroundTask();
bt.execute("second_query")'
```

**Method 3: if this class is inside another class, use this way**

```
new BackgroundTask.execute(type);
```

if you have any other questions feel free to ask ...

Comment: nice answer man, thanks alot bro really helped me alot once again :)